# Run Length Decoding Python:String index out of range error

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a code in Python which decodes run length encoding. So for example:

```
print(decode(a3b3c3))
```

Would return:

```
aaabbbccc
```

However, if I input double digit numbers for the quantity such as:

```
a10b3c2
```

It throws a string index error

How could I fix my code so that it accepts numbers other than single digit ones?

```
def decode(text):
    if not text:
        return ""
    else:
        char, no, i = text[0], int(text[1]), 1
        i+=1
        return char*no + decode(text[i:])

print(encode(a10b2c3))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to parse string with number indexing, which is never a good idea. What if the number has 3 or 4 digits? Best way it's do it with regular expression, example here:

```
import re

def decode(text):
    for (char, num) in re.findall(r'([a-z])([0-9]+)', text):
        yield char * int(num)

print(''.join(decode('a10b2c3')))
```

Prints:

```
aaaaaaaaaabbccc
```

Comment: um, Im not fluent in python (as you can see from the code haha) Can you explain what this part of the code does: re.findall(r'([a-z])([0-9]+)', text), this is my first time seeing someone use regular expression

Comment: @DungNguyen this regular expression tries to find multiple two-member groups in the string (first group is one character from a to z, the second group is digits from 0 to 9). I made online regex, there it is explained: https://regex101.com/r/OQ8ohc/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`more_itertools.run_length.decode()`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.run_length).

**Given**

```py
import more_itertools as mit


compressed = [(char, int(n)) for char, n in mit.sliced("a3b3c3", 2)]
```

**Code**

```py
"".join(mit.run_length.decode(compressed))
# 'aaabbbccc'
```

**Details**

The `compressed` value simply prepares the input as (character, number) pairs, which is required in this particular API.

```py
compressed
# [('a', 3), ('b', 3), ('c', 3)]
```

[`more_itertools`](https://github.com/more-itertools/more-itertools) is a third-party library.  Install via `λ pip install more_itertools`